# IOS Now Blocks PowerApps Forms from being opened - any way around this?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, powerapps-forms, settings, apple-ios

I have a powerapps form based on a SharePoint list with just standard text, date, and people picker columns.  If a user has an iPhone, there are restrictions.  The customer doesn't want to ask their users to enable cookies and download an app in order to access and fill out the form.  Right now, it requires 2-step authentication and changing phone settings in order to do that.

So my question is, is there a way around this?  I tried InfoPath, but it still required cookies to be enabled.  Would a default SP form be a workaround?  It was suggested that I try SPFX for this, though I'm not sure that's a solution.

Any help, guidance, or advise would be super helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As long as a plain SharePoint form does not cause the issues you described, then an SPFx-based form should not cause issues either. Provided your SPFx form is simple enough.